# Express request with middleware called twice with express-namespace

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

node.js(v0.10.15)

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"express": "~3.3.5",
"express-namespace": "~0.1.1",
},
```

app.coffee

```
...
app = module.exports = express()
server = http.createServer(app)


app.configure () ->
  app.use express.compress()
  app.use express.bodyParser()
  app.use express.cookieParser()
  app.use express.favicon()
  app.use express.session({secret: '343453wEFsda'})
  app.use express.static( __dirname + '/public')
  app.use app.router
(require('./routes'))(app)
app.listen(3000);
```

routes.coffee

```
test1 = (req, res,next) ->
  console.log("twice? what the...")
  next();

test = (req, res, next) ->
  console.log("once!");
  next();


routes = (app) ->
  app.namespace '/', test1,  ->
    app.get '/', test, (req, res) ->
      res.send('');

    app.post '/', (req, res) ->
      res.send('');

module.exports = routes
```

server logs of request like below:

```
twice? what the...
twice? what the...
once!
```

It doesn't know why middleware called twice on single request?

Have you seen like that?

Comment: It was stupid an question. generally "app.namespace" doesn't use to root path... sorry.

Comment: It wasn't a stupid question. Guido's answer to your question helped me figure this out.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using a browser to test it, it is possible that your browser makes a second request when it looks for favicon.ico. Try using curl/wget.

Comment: Using `console.log(req.originalUrl);` confirms this.

Comment: If you don't want to install/use curl, try from a different browser. In my case using MS edge called the middleware twice, but using Firefox called it once!!