# express middleware got called twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

in app.js I do

```
const { authMiddleware } = require('./utils/authMiddleware')
var app = express();

app.use('/api', authMiddleware, require('./routes/upload-image'))
app.use('/api', require('./routes/user'))
app.use('/api', authMiddleware, require('./routes/task'))
app.use('/api', authMiddleware, require('./routes/credit'))
```

and I have authMiddleware.js which has a simple console.log

```
module.exports.authMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
    //res.body.user_id = )
    console.log('get logged in user then set user id to body')
    next()
}
```

The post image endpoint is like this routes/upload-image.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/upload-image', function(req, res) {
    res.json('ok')
});

router.get('/upload-image', function(req, res) { ... })

module.exports = router;
```

When I call localhost:3000/api/upload-image I got the console twice in authMeiddleware, why is it triggered twice?

Comment: When you say: "When I call localhost:3000/api/upload-image", do you mean a POST or a GET to that URL?  Your upload-image router is ONLY responding to a POST so any GET is going to be seen by other routes.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, but I updated my question, in routes/upload-image.js I have multiple route, maybe that's why the `authMiddleware` got triggered twice? or I should put `authMiddeware` in each function in routes/upload-image.js?

Comment: Try adding `console.log(req.method, req.path)` inside `authMiddleware` to see for which path(s) it's getting called. Although for any routes in `./routes/task`, you'd expect the middleware to be called twice. And for routes in `./routes/credit`, three times even.

Comment: called one route.. get upload-image

Comment: In that case, I'm inclined to think that the client is sending two requests. Either that, or you have other routes that use `authMiddleware` and which match the path.

Comment: FYI, the model you are using where you put every request handler on its own router and all with the same `app.use('/api', ....)` is kind of screwy.  It makes it hard to see what the code is doing without seeing all the files at once.  If you're only going to have one route on the router, then there's no need for a router at all.  Just do: `app.post('/api/upload-image', authMiddleware, require('./routes/upload-image'))` and just export a single route handler function (not a router).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266794/express-request-with-middleware-called-twice-with-express-namespace/21953878#21953878