# Middleware was called twice in single request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, backend

Upon running this code, I got a console print twice, indicating that app.use was called twice for every request. not sure why it was printed twice.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use((req, res , next)=>{
    console.log("its middleware")
    res.send("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
})

app.listen(3000)
```

I have attached a screenshot for reference:

[image]

Note: i havn't used fevicon.

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: As well as the main document request, the browser makes another request for the favicon, which is probably what you're seeing here. Common practice is to set up a [static directory](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) and serve your favicon (and other static assets) from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express request with middleware called twice with express-namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266794/express-request-with-middleware-called-twice-with-express-namespace)

Comment: No it doesn't helped me. its asking to try curl/wget. but i want to test it in chrome only. is there any solution that can fix this in chrome browser.